# How do I know that the number is halfway in between

Tags: binary

I was shown the following:

$$ 0.110 < 0.1101 < 0.111$$

and told that the middle number is halfway in between those two numbers. Is this correct? How can I see that?

**Update:**

If I add a zero to the first and the last number, I get:

$$ 0.1100 < 0.1101 < 0.1110$$

Now, let write out the last two digits and we can see the relationship:

$$ \underbrace{00 < 01 < 10}_{base-2} = \underbrace{0 < 1 < 2}_{base-10} $$

Comment: Place a $0$ at the end of the first and last numbers

Comment: I've done it and updated my answer, can you please see if that's what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
0.1100 &= 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} \\
0.1101 &= 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + 2^{-4} \\
0.1110 &= 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + 2^{-3} = 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + 2\cdot2^{-4}
\end{align}

Therefore, the difference between $0.1100$ and $0.1101$ as well as between $0.1101$ and $0.1110$ is $2^{-4}$, and hence $0.1101$ does indeed lie halfway between the two other numbers.

Comment: thanks, this explanation seems the most intuitive to me

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the average of $0.110$ and $0.111$, by adding them and dividing the result by $2$ (keep in mind that it is binary), and see that you get $0.1101$.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there an easier way to see this relationship, like the one suggested by Ahmed

Comment: @Maximus Mathematically equivalent, but perhaps more intuitive is to calculate the differences $0.1101 - 0.110$ and $0.111 - 0.1101$ and see that you get the same number.

Comment: thanks, can you please tell me whether the logic presented in my update is valid?

Comment: @Maximus It seems valid, yes. But I wouldn't _phrase_ it like that. What you have done is the following: 1) Multiply all the numbers by $1000$ 2) Subtract $1100$ 3) Convert to base ten to inspect the values. Perhaps you should convince yourself that none of these three steps ruins  the "halfwayness" that you're checking for.

Comment: thanks. Here is the other explanation. Can I say that the number is always two times more that the number following it? For example, in the fraction `0.111=0+1/2+1/4+1/8` the second number is two times larger than the third, so any number `0.111...(1*X)` will be two times larger, than `0.111...(0*X)1`?